# Encrypt and Authenticate localhost-traffic?

Tags: security, encryption, localhost

I have some app-components on the same machine but in different languages that need to communicate. I am using socket communication over localhost to do so. The data transferred is confidential.

Should this communication be encrypted?

I mean an attacker would have to be able to run code on the machine in order to intercept this and in that case the user lost anyway, right?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security concepts and belongs on [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/).